# how can i copy multiple string values into the clipboard in android?

Tags: java, android, copy, clipboard

how can I copy multiple string value into the clipboard in the android? I want to copy all the textView values at once. here I try this but it won't work. I don't know where I made mistake. help me.

```
public void CopyData(){
    String CopyDay =textViewDay.getText().toString().trim();
    String CopyMonth =textViewDay.getText().toString().trim();
    String CopyYear =textViewDay.getText().toString().trim();

    if (CopyDay.isEmpty()&&CopyMonth.isEmpty()&&CopyYear.isEmpty()){

        editTextDay.setError("Please Enter day");
        editTextDay.requestFocus();
        return;

    }

    String Result = "Day ="+CopyDay+"\n"
            +"Month ="+CopyMonth+"\n"
            +"Year ="+CopyYear;

   // Toast.makeText(this, ""+Result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)
            getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

    ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("",Result);
    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);


    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Copied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();

}
```

Comment: Then what is the problem? You copy one string. That looks ok. What do you get back then at paste?

Comment: i get the result in emulator Day = 0 | Month = 0 | Year = 0 and an android Device Day = 1 | Month = 1 | Year = 1 . i don't know why hepend this

Comment: Then what did you put in?

Comment: `CopyMonth =textViewDay.getText().toString().trim()`. Shouldnt that be: `CopyMonth =textViewMonth.getText().toString().trim()` ? Year is wrong too.

Comment: I test your code in my Device and in my Emulator. TextView default text was "test" so it should copy  "Day = test | Month = test | Year = test" and its work perfect.